# Why did "new questions" bar disappear?

Tags: discussion, questions

I used to watch new questions and if the system detected them a bar was appearing with "New questions, click to load them" or something like that.

But now it seems like it disappeared. Do I have to reload the whole website to see the newest questions?

Seriously?

Comment: No repro. Do you have JS enabled?

Comment: I've noticed MSE pop up with new questions, but I've been sitting on SO for a few minutes now with no update, no error in console, just... nothin

Comment: That hasn't worked for me for *years*. Ever since the "new" (now old and defunct after the "new new") nav came around.

Comment: @TylerH It worked like 1yr ago but now... nothing...

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the live question update has *never* been enabled on Stack Overflow, for the same reason that you do not drink from a fire hose. It works on Meta, and on other SE sites, as long as you have JavaScript enabled. Live refresh also works on SO for edits to individual posts.

Comment: Patrick, it's not clear to me in which view you are when you expect the notification? When I'm looking at a list of questions in a tag or tag filter (my usual way to use the site) I do see a gray bar that says something like "New questions, click here". At least, I was seeing it until yesterday. Today I haven't been on the site, however, so I don't know if it's no longer working... Add to that the fact that the site tells me it no longer supports IE as a browser, so any change might be due to that or to using a different browser...

Comment: @CindyMeister It doesnt work for me in newest Chrome. That bar basically doesnt appear anymore. I have to reload whole site to see new questions. Also I disabled my adblocker, still doesnt work

Comment: @CodyGray I think that it doesnt work for other users as well. I would really appreciate if anyone from SO dev team could take a peek whats going on in here.

Comment: @Zoe JS of course enabled:)

Comment: Live question updates still work for me. Can you give an example link of where you were able to see new questions come in previously, but aren't able to anymore? Eg, for me, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&pageSize=50) link works (as it always has), whereas [this](https://stackoverflow.com/) link, the front page, doesn't (and it never has).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Fug, it works. I was sure that it also worked on the main page with all questions. But seems like it works only for specified tags. Maybe a future request so it would also load new questions on main page? Thanks anyways!